# Building memo text for Inno Download Plugin

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

I have reviewed the help documentation for IDP and I cannot find any functions for building the memo text of the files to download.

Previously I was using DwinsHs and it has been giving me problems. But I was able to use:

```pascal
function DwinsHs_MemoDownloadInfo(Space, NewLine: String): String;
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    for i := 0 to GetArrayLength(DwinsHs_DownloadsList) - 1 do
    begin
        if DwinsHs_DownloadsList[i].Required then
        begin
                Result := Result + Space + ExtractFileName(DwinsHs_DownloadsList[i].Filename);
                if DwinsHs_DownloadsList[i].Downloaded then
                begin
                    Result := Result + Space + ExpandConstant('{cm:ReadyMemo_Downloaded}');
                end;
                Result := Result + NewLine;
        end;
    end;
    if Result <> '' then
    begin
        Result := ExpandConstant('{cm:ReadyMemo_Download}') + NewLine + Result;
    end;
end;
```

So, potentially we have up to 4 items that will be downloaded:

- Help Documentation setup
- VC Redist x86
- VC Redist x64
- Dot Net Framework

The relevant files are added using `idpAddFile` (although I don't specify file sizes so there is a little delay). I have asked it to show the download page after `wpPreparing`:

```pascal
idpDownloadAfter(wpPreparing);
```

Ideally, on the memo page I would like it to list the files that we have determined the user wants to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what files you are downloading, so collect their names at the time you are calling `idpAddFile`. You can make a wrapper function as a replacement for `idpAddFile`.

```pascal
var
  FilesToDownload: string;

procedure AddFileForDownload(Url, Filename: string);
begin
  idpAddFile(Url, Filename);
  FilesToDownload := FilesToDownload + '      ' + ExtractFileName(FileName) + #13#10;
end;
```