# Including a summary of the files to download with Inno Setup 6.1.1 beta to Ready page?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

With **Inno Download Plugin** I had a code that registers a list of files to download and adds the list to *"Ready"* page memo at the same time:
[Building memo text for Inno Download Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62460884/850848)

I have modified the code to work with Inno Setup 6.1.1 download page, instead of IDP:

```pascal
procedure AddFileForDownload(Url, FileName: string);
begin
    DownloadPage.Add(Url, FileName, '');
    FilesToDownload := FilesToDownload + '      ' + ExtractFileName(FileName) + #13#10;
    Log('File to download: ' + Url);
end;
```

Then I adjusted `NextButtonClick` like this:

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: integer): boolean;
begin
    Result := True;
 
    if (CurPageID = wpReady) then
    begin
        DownloadPage.Clear;
        if (dotNetNeeded) then begin
            { We need to download the 4.6.2 setup from the Microsoft Website }
            dotNetRedistPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
            AddFileForDownload(dotnetRedistURL, 'NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
        end;

        if (bVcRedist64BitNeeded) then
        begin
            { We need to download the 64 Bit VC Redistributable from the Microsoft Website }
            vcRedist64BitPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\vc_redist.x64.exe');
            AddFileForDownload(vcRedist64BitURL, 'vc_redist.x64.exe');
        end;

        if (bVcRedist32BitNeeded) then
        begin
            { We need to download the 32 Bit VC Redistributable from the Microsoft Website }
            vcRedist32BitPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\vc_redist.x86.exe');
            AddFileForDownload(vcRedist32BitURL, 'vc_redist.x86.exe');
        end;

        if (WizardIsTaskSelected('downloadhelp')) then
            AddFileForDownload('{#HelpDocSetupURL}', 'HelpDocSetup.exe');

        DownloadPage.Show;
        try
          try
            DownloadPage.Download;
            Result := True;
          except
            SuppressibleMsgBox(AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage), mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
            Result := False;
          end;
        finally
          DownloadPage.Hide;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

I ran the installer, and checked the wizard option to download the help documentation, and yet the **Ready** page displays only:

[image: Installer]

The **Download** section is not being added. How can that be? When I click **Next** it does continue to the next page to download the file.

I added some extra logging for `FilesToDownload` and it is interesting:

```
2020-11-01 11:44:22.409   UpdateReadyMemo FileToDownload: 
2020-11-01 11:44:25.671   File to download: https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/downloads/MSAHelpDocumentationSetup.exe
2020-11-01 11:44:25.671   FileToDownload:       HelpDocSetup.exe
```

The `UpdateReadyMemo` method is being called **before** we populate the variable. Confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got confused a bit initially. Because the issue is obvious. Your code executes when you click *"Install"* button on the *"Ready"* page. So obviously only after the *"Ready"* page shows.

You have to call the `AddFileForDownload` earlier. Maybe to `NextButtonClick(wpSelectTasks)`.

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if (CurPageID = wpSelectTasks) then
  begin
    DownloadPage.Clear;
    if (dotNetNeeded) then
    begin
      // We need to download the 4.6.2 setup from the Microsoft Website
      dotNetRedistPath :=
        ExpandConstant('{tmp}\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
      AddFileForDownload(
        dotnetRedistURL, 'NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe');
    end;

    if (bVcRedist64BitNeeded) then
    begin
      // We need to download the 64 Bit VC Redistributable
      // from the Microsoft Website
      vcRedist64BitPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\vc_redist.x64.exe');
      AddFileForDownload(vcRedist64BitURL, 'vc_redist.x64.exe');
    end;

    if (bVcRedist32BitNeeded) then
    begin
      // We need to download the 32 Bit VC Redistributable
      // from the Microsoft Website
      vcRedist32BitPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\vc_redist.x86.exe');
      AddFileForDownload(vcRedist32BitURL, 'vc_redist.x86.exe');
    end;

    if (WizardIsTaskSelected('downloadhelp')) then
      AddFileForDownload('{#HelpDocSetupURL}', 'HelpDocSetup.exe');
  end
    else
  if (CurPageID = wpReady) then
  begin
    DownloadPage.Show;
    try
      try
        DownloadPage.Download;
        Result := True;
      except
        SuppressibleMsgBox(
          AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage), mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    finally
      DownloadPage.Hide;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

*(untested)*